# Run python-script as terminal program (without .py-file-ending) from anywhere on Windows Server 2016

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

On Windows Server 2012R2, how would I go about making a specific python-script (`D:/App/applic.py`) executable from the terminal at any directory without evoking neither `python` nor the `.py` file-ending? On this server, I would like all users to be able to type:

`applic 2017 -v`

anywhere in the terminal to evoke

`python D:/Applic_dev/applic.py 2017 -v`

I'm not looking for a py2exe-kind of solution since Python 3 will always be *on* the server.

PS. My python-script uses `plac` to parse commandline arguments.

Comment: Wrong forum? I can't tell. Borderline subject. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: `function applic() {& python "D:/Applic_dev/applic.py"}`?

Comment: Not a Powershell solution, but I guess you will take anything that works. You could create a batch file named `applic.bat` and include the Python call in there. `py D:/Applic_dev/applic.py %*`. After that you can execute `applic 2017 -v` easily. (`py.exe` is usually installed into the Windows directory and picks a python run-time automatically)

Comment: You could wrap it into `applic.bat` which calls `python applic.py` and passes all arguments.

Comment: Oh and `New-Alias applic applic.py`

Comment: Is Python in the PATH?

Comment: @Clijsters Aliases are not saved between sessions without a profile.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 You no say? functions (my last comment) also.

Comment: Python is in the PATH, yes. Just left work (GMT+1). Will attack the .bat-thing tomorrow. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a cmd file in a protected location (where users cannot edit it)

*applic.cmd*

```
@ECHO OFF
REM This will be wherever the python executable is
SET "PY=%PROGRAMFILES%\Pythonx.x\python.exe"

REM This checks to see if the script is called without arguments
IF [%*] EQU [] (
    @CALL %PY% "D:/App/applic.py"
    EXIT /B
)
REM %* contains all arguments the script received
@CALL %PY% "D:/App/applic.py" %*
EXIT /B
```

From here, edit your PATH environment variable to include the path where this protected location is.

[Automated PowerShell way](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/07/23/use-powershell-to-modify-your-environmental-path/)

```
$ProtectedFolderLocation = 'C:\Windows\System32\Applic'
$RegKey = 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'

$Path = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey).Path
If ($Path[-1] -ne ';') { $Path += ";$ProtectedFolderLocation;" }
Else { $Path += "$ProtectedFolderLocation;" }

Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name 'PATH' -Value $Path
```

Now when users call `applic` from `cmd.exe`, they'll be calling the script specified above.

Comment: Yes indeed! However... the line `"PY=%PROGRAMFILES%\Pythonx.x\python.exe"` aught to have been `PY="%PROGRAMFILES%\Pythonx.x\python.exe"`, but perfect.   I'll also need to automate commands to my applic.py, and I take it that lines of `@CALL applic something` to another .cmd-file could do the trick.  Also, I will never talk badly about bash ever again ;)   Thank you very much

Comment: @nJGL best practice actually states to wrap the entire argument in quotes as well, I forgot there's a space in the path: `SET "PY="%PROGRAMFILES%\Pythonx.x\python.exe""`

Comment: @nJGL The reason for this is SET will take everything after the initial space as the argument until the end of line.  This way avoids misc. spaces or hidden characters

Comment: Ah. Thanks. The whole thing quote-wrapped it is.